# PhysX Collision Filter with Dynamic & Static Rigidbodies

Tags: c++, game-physics, nvidia, physics-engine, physx

I'm developing a videogame engine and I'm implementing PhysX 3.4, specifically I'm currently working on Colliders Filtering and I've been testing the FilterShader() function (from [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/AdvancedCollisionDetection.html#continuous-collision-detection) and [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/RigidBodyCollision.html) Nvidia documentation) with some colliders and rigidbodies.
So, if both colliders have a dynamic rigidbody the, function gives me the pxFilterData of both, but if one of them is static it gives me only 1 pxFilterData and in the next iteration the other one.

Is it possible to receive both of them as it does when both are dynamic?

Comment: Solved by first creating the shape, then calling shape->setSimulationFilterData() and finally creating the rigidbody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by creating first the shape and then calling setSimulationFilterData(), before creating the rigidbody